# Generate JSON payload for posting to API with keys from 1 file and values from the other file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, python-requests

I have a use case where I need to generate a JSON payload for each individual in the data file. Each data file will have a config file associated with it. The data file and corresponding config file look somewhat like this.

File 1(Data file):

```
Employee ID,First Name,Last Name,Email
E1000,Manas,Jani,jam@xyz.com
E2000,Jim,Kong,jik@xyz.com
E3000,Olila,Jayavarman,olj@xyz.com
E4000,Lisa,Kopkingg,lik@xyz.com
E5000,Kishore,Pindhar,kip@xyz.com
E6000,Gobi,Nadar,gon@xyz.com
```

File 2(Config file):

```
Input_file_column_name,Config_file_column_name,Value
Employee_ID,employee_Id,idTypeCode:001
First Name,first_Name 
Last Name,last_Name   
Email,email_Address   
EntityID,entity_Id,01
```

As you can see, each element in the data file is there on the config file. The config file contains the actual rules in terms of what the field should be named as per the JSON payload. Also, there could be fields with a value associated on it and that needs to be put into the JSON payload to be passed to the API built.

The **input_file_column_name** is the name in the input data file but the JSON payload will take the column name as per the **config_file_column_name**.

This is how my post JSON request should look like:

```
{"IndividualInfo":[{"employee_Id":"E1000","first_Name":"Manas","last_Name":"Jani","email_Address":"jam@xyz.com","entity_Id":01,"idTypeCode":001},{"employee_Id":"E2000","first_Name":"Jim","last_Name":"Kong","email_Address":"jik@xyz.com","entity_Id":01,"idTypeCode":001},{"employee_Id":"E3000","first_Name":"Olila","last_Name":"Jayavarman","email_Address":"olj@xyz.com","entity_Id":01,"idTypeCode":001},{"employee_Id":"E4000","first_Name":"Lisa","last_Name":"Kopkingg","email_Address":"lik@xyz.com","entity_Id":01,"idTypeCode":001},{"employee_Id":"E5000","first_Name":"Kishore","last_Name":"Pindhar","email_Address":"kip@xyz.com","entity_Id":01,"idTypeCode":001},{"employee_Id":"E6000","first_Name":"Gobi","last_Name":"Nadar","email_Address":"gon@xyz.com","entity_Id":01,"idTypeCode":001}]}
```

I am unable to understand how to replace the keys once I generate the payload from the data file as well as add those extra elements which have the **VALUE** field filled up. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

This is what I have in terms of code:

```
import json 
import requests
import pandas as pd

file1='Onboarding_members.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(open(file1))
#print df.to_json(orient='records')
print df

file2='Onboarding_config.txt'
df1=pd.read_csv(open(file2))
#saved_column=df1['Config_file_name']
#print saved_column
print df1

df.columns = df.columns.map(df1.set_index('Input_file_name')['Config_file_name'].get)

#df2=df.rename(columns=df1.set_index('Input_file_name')['Config_file_name'], inplace=True)

print df
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert at Python 2.X, but here's a broken down code snippet to get you started.
Using this snippet as a starting point, you can hopefully fine-tune it to your own needs.

The CSV source I'm using:

`src.csv`

```
Employee ID,First Name,Last Name,Email
E1000,Manas,Jani,jam@xyz.com
E2000,Jim,Kong,jik@xyz.com
E3000,Olila,Jayavarman,olj@xyz.com
E4000,Lisa,Kopkingg,lik@xyz.com
E5000,Kishore,Pindhar,kip@xyz.com
E6000,Gobi,Nadar,gon@xyz.com
```

Here's the code to parse the csv, create a dictionary for each person and wrap them up into a list:

`example.py`

```
import csv
import io

path = "/tmp/csvTst/src.csv"

employees = []
with io.open(path, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        employees.append(
            {
                "Employee ID": row['Employee ID'],
                "First Name": row['First Name'],
                "Last Name": row['Last Name'],
                "Email": row['Email']
            }
        )

print employees
```

To post with the requests library, you don't need to import json. You're request would look something like this:

```
for employee in employees:
    requests.post("https://my-site.com/api/users/", json=employee)
```

Of course, you can make this more sophisticated by automatically assigning the csv's first row as keys to your dictionary without manually hard-coding it, but I wanted to make the snippet as simple as possible.

Comment: No, that is not my question. I can easily generate a JSON using the data file with the to_json function. I need to work with the config file and create the JSON payload according to the names given under the "config_file_name" column, if you get what I am trying to say!